# Supress logging of embedded youtube iFrame

Tags: youtube-api

When playing a video with the embedded iFrame youtube player, I get a lot of logs in the console. Is there a way to disable this?

I already found an issue posted on [the google forum](https://developers.google.com/youtube/forum/discussion?place=topic/youtube-api-gdata/8AiSKiQiro8/discussion) but it isn't solved yet.

Some examples of the logs:

```
SDK Loader major version = 3
SDK Version = 3.0.48
Loading xlb file for locale - en
Loaded xlb file for locale - en succeed
en_US is not supported. Attempting to trim locale.
Loading xlb file for locale - en
Loaded xlb file for locale - en succeed
```

Comment: To make sure we track this, can you pls file a bug using the process described here: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html?

Comment: Ok, done! See https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4098&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of enabling or disabling but a case of extensive logging. It's fixed now:

> This inadvertent logging was a bit of an edge case, and it should be fixed later tonight.
>   (Feb 13, 2013)
>   See [posted issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4098&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)